# Smartfield annotation for showing names of the key variables does not work. Do you have any idea about it?

Tags: annotations, sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I implement annotation as shown is SDK, but it doesn't affect my smartfield. Still, it shows only key value. But I want to show that like 'description(key)'. Do you have any idea?

**My annotation code:**

```
            <Annotations Target="xxx.xxSh/Posid">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Text" Path="Post1">
                    <Annotation Term="UI.TextArrangement" EnumMember="UI.TextArrangementType/TextLast"/>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="xxx.xxar/Parnr">
                <Annotation Term="UI.TextArrangement" EnumMember="UI.TextArrangementType/TextFirst"/>
                <Annotation Term="Common.ValueList">
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListType">
                        <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="xxShSet"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="SearchSupported" Bool="true"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                            <Collection>
                                <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
                                    <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Post1"/>
                                </Record>
                                <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterInOut">
                                    <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="Parnr"/>
                                    <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Posid"/>
                                </Record>
                            </Collection>
                        </PropertyValue>
                    </Record>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
```

**my xml code:**

```
<smartField:SmartField value="{Parnr}" textInEditModeSource="ValueList" change="onParnrChange">
                                            <smartField:configuration>
                                                <smartField:Configuration preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"/>
                                            </smartField:configuration>
                                        </smartField:SmartField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this to the xml? This will display description and Id.                       `<smartField:configuration> <smartField:Configuration displayBehaviour="descriptionAndId"/> </smartField:configuration>`